# How to use SymPy to substitute a pattern

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

In my code I need to substitute ALL the expressions of `sin(g(t))` (`g` being a continuous function) to `g(t)` (it's the tight angle approximation). This is a sample of what I get from my code:

```
-29.4*sin(2*t) - 19.6*sin(f(t)) + 4.0*Derivative(f(t), t)**2
```

I need to substitute both `sin(f(t))` and `sin(2*t)`. Not just one of them and `sin(2*t)` changes, (`sin(f(t))` is always the same). Is there a simpler way than adding an extra variable for what's inside the `sin` or isn't there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.symbols('t')
f = sp.Function('f')

expr_v1 = -29.4*sp.sin(2*t) - 19.6*sp.sin(f(t)) + 4.0*sp.Derivative(f(t), t)**2
print('expr_v1 = ', expr_v1)

expr_v2 = expr_v1.replace(sp.sin, lambda *args: args[0])
print('expr_v2 = ', expr_v2)
```

> ```
> expr_v1 =  -29.4*sin(2*t) - 19.6*sin(f(t)) + 4.0*Derivative(f(t),t)**2
> expr_v2 =  -58.8*t - 19.6*f(t) + 4.0*Derivative(f(t), t)**2
> ```